# Do,does, is and are with multiple subjects

Tags: grammar

i m really confused about these two things:
First this : is emma stone and sharon stone related or are emma stone and sharon stone related?
2nd question: do your girlfriend and her friends want to eat? Or does your girlfriend and her friend want to eat?

Thanks

Comment: Your examples have plural subjects, so use "are" and "do".

Comment: Two singular noun phrases, each referring to something different, become plural when they are conjoined with _and_, but remain singular when disjoined with _or_. With a reciprocal predicate like _be related (to)_, one can have either singular or plural verbs, depending: _Emma and Sharon are related; Emma is related to Sharon; Sharon is related to Emma._ I have no idea whether those sentences are true, btw; but they're certainly grammatical.